How to install JDownloader? X Server not found and directory name must not contain spaces error
I'm on Fedora 39 KDE. I downloaded the "JDownloader2Setup_unix_nojre.sh" file from https://jdownloader.org/jdownloader2.
The installer doesn't work.
./JDownloader2Setup_unix_nojre.sh 
Starting Installer ...
Could not display the GUI. This application needs access to an X Server.
*******************************************************************
You can also run this application in unattended mode without
access to an X server by passing the argument -q
*******************************************************************

"The directory name must not contain spaces." error:
./JDownloader2Setup_unix_nojre.sh -q
Starting Installer ...
The installation directory has been set to /home/user/jd2/JDownloader 2.
The directory name must not contain spaces.
[1/1|Priority: 0]ShutdownController: start item->ShutdownEvent: Save JSonStorages
[1/1|Priority: 0]ShutdownController: item ended after->2
[Done:1/1]
Shutdown Hooks Finished


You have a directory name that contains a space, and you got an error message that says that that’s not OK.   What is your question?

@G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' "/home/user/jd2/JDownloader 2" is what the installer used by default. I didn't pick it.

The weirdest thing for me is that whatever directory I choose it always adds "/Jdownloader 2" to that, then complains that there's a space in there. The script itself adds the space and then complains. Why?!?

I was able to get the unattended installer working (but not the GUI mode).
Install latest Java
After installing JDownloader, it got an "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-17.0.9.0.9-3.fc39.x86_64/lib/libawt_xawt.so" error on OpenJDK 17, so I had to switch to the latest OpenJDK 22.

Installing Java:
https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/installing-java/


# Install latest OpenJDK.
sudo dnf install java-latest-openjdk-devel.x86_64 java-latest-openjdk.x86_64

# Switch to latest OpenJDK.
sudo alternatives --config java

# Confirm Java version.
java --version

Install in unattended mode
To use the unattended mode, you need to create and provide a "response.varfile" file.

[Solved] Mode unattended new installer
https://board.jdownloader.org/showthread.php?t=28335


"response.varfile" file:
sys.fileAssociation.launchers$StringArray="26","26","26","26","26"
sys.languageId=en
customTab$Boolean=false
customBasic$Boolean=true
sys.installationDir=/opt/JDownloader
customSearch$Boolean=false
customHomepage$Boolean=false
executeLauncherAction$Boolean=false
sys.fileAssociation.extensions$StringArray="dlc","jdc","ccf","rsdf","metalink"
installFM=skip

Set the "sys.installationDir". For example, I installed to "/opt/JDownloader".
# Create JDownloader installation directory.
sudo mkdir /opt/JDownloader
sudo chmod 777 /opt/JDownloader

./JDownloader2Setup_unix_nojre.sh -q -varfile "response.varfile"

Success:
Starting Installer ...
The installation directory has been set to /opt/JDownloader.
Import proxyList
null
StepID: CREATE_PACKAGE
StepID: DOWNLOAD
StepID: EXTRACTION
StepID: PREPARE_INSTALL
StepID: PREPARE_INSTALL
StepID: INSTALLING
StepID: INSTALLING
StepID: CLIENT_OPTIONS
StepID: CLEANUP
StepID: CREATE_PACKAGE
StepID: DOWNLOAD
StepID: EXTRACTION
StepID: PREPARE_INSTALL
StepID: PREPARE_INSTALL
StepID: INSTALLING
StepID: INSTALLING
StepID: CLIENT_OPTIONS
StepID: CLEANUP
CustomProxyListPath: /opt/JDownloader/cfg/org.jdownloader.settings.InternetConnectionSettings.customproxylist.json
[1/3|Priority: 0]ShutdownController: start item->ShutdownEvent: SaveAllStorageHandler
[1/3|Priority: 0]ShutdownController: item ended after->0
[Done:1/3]
[2/3|Priority: 0]ShutdownController: start item->ShutdownEvent: ProcessDelayedWrites num=0
[2/3|Priority: 0]ShutdownController: item ended after->0
[Done:2/3]
[3/3|Priority: 0]ShutdownController: start item->ShutdownEvent: Save JSonStorages
[3/3|Priority: 0]ShutdownController: item ended after->1
[Done:3/3]
Shutdown Hooks Finished


Just running the commands you specified and then running the installer again worked. Kinda strange to me in how that lower-than-required version error manifests…

I got the exact same error and solved it by installing jre-openjdk and jre-openjdk-headless.
